# Struggling to resolve Tap Hold Manager Lshift and Rshift key conflict

Tags: autohotkey

I have been trying to solve this issue for the better part of yesterday and I seem to be getting nowhere.

I want to use  `Lshift` and `Rshift` as a standalone triggers and also be able to use them as modifiers to trigger combinations like `LShift`+`a`/ `Rshift`+`a`/`Lshift`+`Rshift`+`a`.

Using `Lshift` and `Rshift` as standalone triggers seems to work fine, the issue arises as soon as I define a hotkey like `Lshift`+`a`, then the single tap action for `Lshift` is always fired, no matter if `Lshift` was tapped twice or held down.

The following example demonstrates what I mean, the only way to get 2x Taps/ Hold of `Lshift` to work is to comment out `test.add("<+a", Func("LShift_a"))`, its the same with `Rshift`:

```
#singleinstance, force
#NoEnv
#include <TapHoldManager>

test        := new TapHoldManager(110, 130, 2)

test.Add("LShift", Func("LShift"))
test.Add("RShift", Func("RShift"))

test.add("<+a", Func("LShift_a"))                
test.add("<+>+a", Func("LShift_RShift_a"))

LShift(isHold, taps, state)
{
    if (taps == 1)
    {
        if (isHold == 0)
        {
            Tooltip, LShift Tap 1
        }
        else
        {
          if (state)
                        {
                            Tooltip, LShift Hold 1
                        }
              ; else 
              ;           {
              ;           } 
        }
    }
}
RShift(isHold, taps, state)
{
    if (taps == 1)
    {
        if (isHold == 0)
        {
            Tooltip, RShift Tap 1
        }
        else
        {
          if (state)
                        {
                            Tooltip, RShift Hold 1
                        }
              ; else 
              ;           {
              ;           } 
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried messing with prefixes such as `~*$` in `test.add("*$<+a", Func("LShift_a"))`, did not work.

The issue seems to be down to specifying  left and right Shift in `...add("<+a"...`, if I just do `test.add("+a", Func("LShift_a"))`, **LShift** function goes back to working probably but then this means I have no way of distinguishing `Lshift` from `Rshift`.

I have tried using `Lwin`/`Rwin` as a modifier and quickly relearnt why 2 years ago, I decided against using them, windows native functions such `Win`+`p`, even after all the regedit's they wont stop working.

The following seems to solve the issue but I would really like to avoid using `#if` and multiple `GetKeyState()` and much rather do it directly in TapHoldManager:

```
#if GetKeyState("LShift", "P")
   test.add("a", Func("LShift_a"))
#if GetKeyState("RShift", "P")
   test.add("a", Func("RShift_a"))
#if GetKeyState("LShift", "P") && GetKeyState("RShift", "P")
   test.add("a", Func("LShift_RShift_a"))
```

Thank you for any help.